# Notation for multivariate Lebesgue space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, notation

Are the two vector spaces

$$L^p(\Omega),\text{ with } \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$$

and

$$\left[L^p(\Omega) \right]^d,\text{ with } \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$$

the same?

I have mostly encountered the latter, but would like to avoid typing these weird brackets every time i have to declare this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: $L^p(\Omega)$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ consists of (equivalence classes) of functions from a subset of $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$, while $L^p(\Omega)^d$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$ consists of (equivalence classes) of functions from a subset of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: A follow up question: Is $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ the same as $\left [L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right ]^m$ ?

Comment: yes, they are the same. You can easily write down an isomorphism between them,

Comment: thank you for your answer!